Disconnect Reconnect of winsock2 socket causes application to hang?
I have a winsock2 client/server application that hangs when a client that has already connected to the server on one computer tries to connect to the server again from another computer. The logic in the server code detects this and it disconnects the client from the previously connected socket without any issues but the application that was connected to that socket has no idea it was disconnected and the application hangs when trying to close itself.
The sockets are default blocking sockets and I suspect the closing application is waiting for the client socket to close but since the server has already closed the socket I would assume that not to be the issue.
Any ideas what is causing the application to hang and any ideas on how to fix it?
Connect code...
bool connectSocket(SOCKET &sock, const char *serverIp, const unsigned int serverPort) {

    sockaddr_in serverAddress;

    memset(&serverAddress, 0x00, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serverIp);
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(serverPort);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return false;

    if(connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("connect socket error %u\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return false;
    }
}


Disconnect code...
void disconnectSocket(SOCKET &sock) {

    if(sock != INVALID_SOCKET) {

        if(closesocket(sock) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            printf("close socket error %u\n", WSAGetLastError());

        sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
}

Note: I get not error codes from the code above and if the client connects and disconnects from the server using the same original socket everything works fine.
TIA

This is not C: SOCKET &sock. Please don't tag C++ with C.

This is your client code.  What does the server code look like?  How many connections did you allow in your listen call?

Sockets don't block when closed. Something else in your code is blocking your app. You need to debug your code to find the real culprit.

Thanks for the advice... I'll have to figure out how to debug this C/C++ code. Is GDB the preferred debugger?

Tim just 1 connection while testing produces the issue... my server listener socket can handle requests ok. I think Remy is right I got to get a debugger to find the issue.
